# How to increase read performance with psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have set up a connection to Postgres via psycopg2 library.

I want to query over 10 million rows, but it is taking a long time to create a single data frame.

I tried looping the data every 10,000 rows by using the fetchmany method.

Does anyone here have any suggestion on how I could improve the performance in querying the data?

Comment: Is your query slow (execution of the query) or is the processing of the result set slow? The receive data from the database, copy is the fastest protocol: https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html

Comment: 1) I'm betting it is the data frame(I'm assuming Pandas here). That is a heavy object.  2) Why do you need to create the data frame? 3) This is not going to get a useful answer until: a) You show the code you are actually using? b) Provide an `EXPLAIN ANAYZE` for the query using the `psql` client. FYI, you should also look at [Server side cursors](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors).